# Dúvida sobre uma questão que eu estou tentando resolver tenho esse seguinte código em python:

Tags: python

```
temperaturas_c = [('Argentina', 20), ('Brasil', 30), ('Estados Unidos', 28)]
```

eu possuo uma lista que contém os nomes dos países e a sua temperatura em Celsius numa tupla, eu gostaria de transformar
os valores em celsius em fahrenheit e exibir a mesma lista de tuplas com o nome do país e as temperaturas em fahrenheit

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Para fazer de um jeito bem eficiente vou usar a função `map()` do python no seu código para obter a lista de tuplas com o nome original e a temperatura modificada em Fahrenheit

Então ficaria desse jeito:

```
temperaturas_f = list(map(lambda temp: (temp[0], (9/5) * temp[1] + 32), temperaturas_c))
```

Comment: obrigado, funcionou :)